# Soyuz parachute cord/rope forces

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, parachute

I'm wondering about the forces (e.g., how much pressure is being applied, how much pulling force, etc.) experienced by the ropes of the Soyuz parachutes when they are deployed.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the impulse force when the parachutes deploy (theoretically infinite) or while unfurling or after it reaches a steady state?

Comment: Probably it would be hard to find this info in open media. By quick search in Russian I couldn't find anything relevant. Data from Apollo or/and Dragon can be useful as ballpark, l don't think it's so much different.

Comment: The main parachute opens when the speed of the Soyuz capsule drops to 90 m / s.